# Reading three URLs sequentially

Tags: java, android

I have 3 url's of pages which content has a json structure. I must read a page from an url in an async task.

**How can I read the 3 urls sequentially, so that I can work with the 3 json's maintaining their order?**

```
private class JsonTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        HttpURLConnection connection = null;
        BufferedReader reader = null;

        try {
            URL url = new URL(params[0]);    //params[0] = my first url
            connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.connect();

            InputStream stream = connection.getInputStream();

            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream));

            StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
            String line = "";

            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                buffer.append(line + "\n");
            }

            return buffer.toString();

            //read also the second and the third url


        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        // ... do something with the first json
        // ... do something with the second json
        // ... do something with the third json

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just move the logic for mapping one URL to JSON out into a method, and call it for each argument you pass in. Then, modify your `AsyncTask` so it outputs `List<String>` and not `String` from `doInBackground()`.

```
protected List<String> doInBackground(String... params) {
    final List<String> out = new ArrayList<>(paramas.length);
    for(String url : params) {
        out.add(downloadJson(url));
    }
    return out;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(List<String> results) {
    //A list of your JSON results...
}

private String downloadJson(String url) {

    HttpURLConnection connection = null;
    BufferedReader reader = null;

    try {
        connection = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(url).openConnection();
        connection.connect();

        InputStream stream = connection.getInputStream();

        reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream));

        StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder();
        String line = "";

        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            buffer.append(line).append("\n");
        }

        return buffer.toString();
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
     }
    return "{}"; //Default to an empty JSON object
}
```